# Theme color meta tags not working with specific color

Tags: html, css, meta, android-chrome

A single color, old lace, is not working for me as a theme-color in the meta tag in Chrome Android.

Other colors work well. I tried providing the hex triplet instead and still nothing.

```
<html>
<head>
    ....
    <meta name="theme-color" content="oldlace"> <!-- content="#fdf5e6" doesn't work either -->
    ....
</head>
<body>
    ....
</body>
</html>
```

It just appears as the default white instead of the wanted color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a description from [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#meta-theme-color)

> When using the theme color in UI, user agents **may adjust it** in implementation-specific ways to make it more suitable for the UI in question.

Color `#fdf5e6` is a QUESTION here, because its too light to have a enough contrast.

Same problem with color `#f5f5f5f` and any other light colors.